# How to make Ghidra recognize bit fields?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra

Suppose we have the following C source:

```
typedef struct {
  int bit0 : 1;
  int bit1 : 1;
  int bit2 : 1;
  int bit3 : 1;
} bit_struct;

bit_struct a;

void setBit3()
{
  a.bit3 = 1;
}
```

When we compile it and open the result in Ghidra, the decompilation window shows

```
void setBit3(void)
{
  a = a | 8;
  return;
}
```

If we give Ghidra the declaration of `bit_struct` (using `File` -> `Parse C Source`), and then go to the location of `a` and set its data type to `bit_struct`, the decompilation changes to

```
a = (bit_struct)((byte)a | 8);
```

which still doesn't access `bit3` by declared name.

How can we make Ghidra properly decompile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like full bitfield support for the decompiler is slated for a future release according to a comment on Ghidra's github issues: [Bitfields don't seem to decompile very well #1059](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1059#issuecomment-534651905)